# Can't convert a json list into a DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, facebook-graph-api

Trying to convert a json list into a Panda's DataFrame. My data keep staying in a single row instead of converting into a DataFrame.

- importing data from facebook graph api
- put the data in a json file
- try to read this file and put the data in a dataframe

```
def main():

    token = 'xxx'

    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)

    fields = ["posts{message}"]

    data_interface = graph.get_object('me', fields=fields)

    with open('data_interface.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data_interface, f)


    dataFrame_final = pd.DataFrame()
    df = pd.read_json(r'jason_file.json')
    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df)
    dataFrame_final = dataFrame_final.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

    print(dataFrame_final)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Expect to obtain a dataframe, but get all the data in a single row

Comment: Can we look at the json?

Comment: {"posts": {"data": [{"message": "Chez @ecole_interface nous attaquons un obstacle \u00e0 la fois. Un pas apr\u00e8s l\u2019autre, jour apr\u00e8s jour nous nous effor\u00e7ons de vous guider ...

Answer (score 0):

### Does something like this work?

What is the value of `df` at this point?

```py
    with open('data_interface.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        add_to_df = data['data']


    df = pd.read_json(add_to_df)
```

Comment: something like this:
                                                    posts               id
data    [{'message': 'Chez @ecole_interface nous attaq...  660438427325780
paging  {'cursors': {'before': 'Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNV...  660438427325780

Comment: I updated the snippet - it looks as though you need to access elements within your JSON object. Do this by 'chaining' together what elements you want. 

It looks like 'data' is your most parent element.
`data['data']`

Comment: i got it. Thanks you for your help!